# Infinite loading when my array has more than 30,000 entries

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating an array that consists of more than 30,000 entries. When this array has less values, the code works fine, but when there are more than 30,000 entries, infinite loading occurs and my code does not move further. My PHP code is:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM InitialLog");

$filearray = array();

while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

       array_push($filearray,$row2['FileName']);

}
```

How could this problem be solved? (I have to use this array further somewhere else in the code)

Comment: Upgrade your environment.

Comment: you are only using `FileName` and looking at your code you only want to get no duplicates of `FileName`  this query should be enough for you.   `SELECT FileName FROM InitialLog group by FileName`

Comment: @Chay22 can you elaborate please?

Comment: @roullie's ans is best for this situation

Comment: @roullie The same infinite loading occurs after changing the query to the one mentioned by you.

Comment: @MariumMalik you dont have to check anymore for duplicates since the result will have unique `FileName`'s

Comment: @roullie The same problem occurs when I am creating another array for some other purpose, so this won't be the solution. I need to create array or require some other alternative

Comment: change `array_push($filearray,$row2['FileName']);` to `$filearray[] = $row2['FileName']` to prevent overhead

Comment: @roullie Same problem.

Comment: 30000 -- exact border number? 30000 -- everything is ok, 30001 -- problem occurs?

Comment: @Andrewus initially I had less values like 5000 but when my rows increased to 36000, this started happening. So it is just an approximate

Comment: Would using an unbuffered query work? (Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)